# Java error-message - 'void' type not allowed here, when calling a method that returns an integer

Tags: java, compiler-errors, void, jcreator

I've had a look throughout various forums and sites trying to find out where I'm going wrong but with no luck.

```
public void updatePlayerLabels()
{
    if(currPlayer == 0)
        lblP1Name.setText(lblP1Name.setText(myPlayers[currPlayer].getName() + " - " + myPlayers[currPlayer].getScore()));
    else
        lblP2Name.setText(lblP2Name.setText(myPlayers[currPlayer].getName() + " - " + myPlayers[currPlayer].getScore()));
}
```

the error seems to appear where I call the getScore() methods on both statements. I get 2 "'void' type not allowed here" messages. Here is a snippet of the player class.

```
public Player(int number, String name)
{
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    score = 0;
}

public int getScore()
{
    return score;
}
```

As far as I can tell I should not be seeing that error as I set score to 0 in the constructor and I construct the players before that method is called.

Also I use the getScore() method elsewhere in the code without any problems, I am sure this is the problematic method as when I remove it from those 2 lines the error disappears.

Comment: You're calling setText twice nesting it inside of another!

Comment: What does `lblP1Name.setText(String)` return?

Comment: Thanks for all the swift answers! :) I feel like an idiot when I overlook something like that

Comment: If you're like me, it won't be the last time you get this feeling. Sometimes all you need are another set of eyes to look things over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `lblP1Name.setText()` twice (the second time with the "result" of calling `lblP1Name.setText()`)

It should be:

```
if(currPlayer == 0)
    lblP1Name.setText(myPlayers[currPlayer].getName() + " - " + myPlayers[currPlayer].getScore());
else
    lblP2Name.setText(myPlayers[currPlayer].getName() + " - " + myPlayers[currPlayer].getScore());
```

Comment: Ahh I see it now, Totally missed that when reading over it, Thank you very much that fixed it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads

```
 lblP1Name.setText(lblP1Name.setText(.....));
```

The inner set text call will return the void that is passed to the outer call. This causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
lblP1Name.setText(lblP1Name.setText(...
```

The method `setText()` receives a `String` and returns void, you 're trying to set the text of `lblP1Name` but the inner `lblP1Name.setText` will return void.

Try this instead:

```
public void updatePlayerLabels() {
    if (currPlayer == 0)
        lblP1Name.setText(myPlayers[currPlayer].getName() + " - " + myPlayers[currPlayer].getScore());
    else
        lblP2Name.setText(myPlayers[currPlayer].getName() + " - " + myPlayers[currPlayer].getScore());
}
```